# Linq, select values + - a value

Tags: c#, linq

I need to do a select on a product table.
The product has a column called ZipCode
I need to get alle the products from a specific zipcode, and the 5 zipcode higher and lower than the selected zipcode

so if i have the zipcode 51235
i need the products from 5 higher zipcodes and lower zipcodes, is this possible with linq?

Hope someone can help

Comment: LINQ to what? Entities? SQL? Objects?

Comment: it would help a lot if your zip code is already of numeric type

Comment: "products from 5 higher zipcodes and lower zipcodes" what does this mean ?

Comment: Do you want 5 products that happen to have higher ZipCode, or all products of 5 higher ZipCodes?

Comment: no, lets simplify the zipcode and lets say you have a bunch of products under each zipcode, and the zipcodes are 2, 3 4,7,12,15,17,21,23,25,33,44,77,245,2521,3222, and the selected zipcode was 23, i would want to get products under zipcode 23, and then, 25,33, 44, 77, 245 and 21,17,15,12, 7

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

```
var zip = 51235;
context.Products.Where(p => p.ZipCode >= zip - 5 && p.ZipCode <= zip +5);
```

Or like this:

```
var zip = 51235;
var products = from p in context.Products
where p.ZipCode >= zip -5 && p.ZipCode <= zip + 5
select p;
```

UPDATE:

If you want to do it all in one statement you could do it like this:

```
        var products = Products.Where(p1 => 
                Products.Select(p2 => p2.ZipCode)
                        .Distinct()
                        .Where(p3 => p3 >= zipCode)
                        .Take(4)
                        .Union(
                            Products.Select(p4 => p4.ZipCode)
                            .Distinct()
                            .Where(p5 => p5 < zipCode)
                            .Take(3)
                        ).Contains(p1.ZipCode)
                );
```

But it might be easier to split it up into different statements to keep it more readable.

Comment: Sorry i wasnt clear, the Zipcode could be 51235 and the next is not nesesarey 51235, it could be 51602 for example.. so deducting 5 isnt going to work

Comment: maybe i could sort the list descendently, and select distinct on zipcode, and then get pass into a array and array[1] 2 3 4 5 and -1 -2 -3 -4 -5, just sounds really ugly haha

Answer (score 0):

To get products between zipcode-5 and zipcode+5

```
container.Products.Where(w => (w.ZipCode > zipCode - 5) && (w.ZipCode < zipCode + 5));
```

To get products have their zipcodes exactly equals to zipcode +/- 5 and current zipcode.

```
container.Products.Where(w => (w.ZipCode == zipCode - 5) || (w.ZipCode == zipCode + 5) || (w.ZipCode == zipCode + 5));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use,

```
var collectionEqualToZipCode = SourceCollection.Where(source=> source.Zip == SelectedZip);

int lessZipCodesTaken = 0;
int greaterZipCodesCountTaken = 0;
var collectionlessthanOrGreaterthanZipCode = SourceCollection.TakeWhile(source => 
(source.Zip < SelectedZip && lessZipCodesTaken++ < 5) ||
(source.Zip > SelectedZip && greaterZipCodesCountTaken ++ < 5));
FinalCOllection.AddRange(collectionEqualToZipCode);
FinalCOllection.AddRange(collectionlessthanOrGreaterthanZipCode );
```